# Unable to connect to Ubuntu Server via ssh after ufw rules update

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-lightsail, ufw

I updated ufw on my ubuntu server in aws with the following commands

> Changed the port value in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file to 2200 from 22

```
sudo service ssh restart
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw allow www
sudo ufw allow ntp
sudo ufw enable
```

After these updates, I added the port in networking tab as Custom - 2200

As I try to connect via ssh, the machine launches but a blank black screen appears(screenshot attached)
The prompt is blank after connecting
[image]

What do i need to do to access prompt on the machine

Answer (score 0):

ssh runs on port 22

so when you enabled ssh on UFW, you opened port 22 for accepting connections.
The port 2200 is blocked on your AWS server.

Its advisable to use AWS security groups to manage ports on your machines, instead of using UFW directly.